# Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InvalidReportServerDatabaseException

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I'm getting following error in the General Application Settings-->Reporting Services-->Set Server Defaults section and also viewing reports on SharePoint.

```
The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is ''. The expected version is '162'. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InvalidReportServerDatabaseException: The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is ''. The expected version is '162'.
```

There is SQL Server 2012 on our report server and SQL Server 2008 R2 on this machine, which I'm gettin this error. We will use this machine as our application server in our new farm topology.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RS Add-in for SharePoint installed on my application server but our report server has SQL Server 2008 R2. Can this difference cause this problem? Can I use SQL Server 2012 RS Add-in to view reports from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i´m having the same problem, could you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not. But if I find any solutions, I am going to type it here.